# How to move all instances of a specific word or phrase to a particular column number in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm unsure if this is possible, but I need to move all instances of the word `USA` to column `130` in a txt document using Notepad++.

I didn't "think" this would require any regex so I posted here, however I'm beginning to think otherwise.

I primarily need to know how to move just `USA` but knowing how to move it including everything after would be great so I don't have to come back and ask again. I tend to file these things away mentally or in a file to reference.

Example:

```
<titleid> <titlekey> <title> <random-number-of-spaces>     USA System Application

<titleid> <titlekey> <title> <random-number-of-spaces> USA System Application
```

Operating under the assumption the final result has the U from USA landing on column 130. I'd like to know how to move it by itself to that point, as well as it and everything beyond it if possible.

I have been able to scrape up some expressions to move forward by x number of tabs or preceding spaces, but nothing to move backwards.  This is made complicated by the fact the end of the previous word, the `<title>` is of differing lengths and some instances of `USA` need to move forward, some backward, all need to end on the same column.  Thus none fit what I am trying to accomplish.

For reference
find `\h+(?=USA\b)` replace `\t` will handle moving forward by the number of tabs set in language preferences.

find `(?:(USA.+))` replace `$1` will move forward by the number of spaces preceding the `$1` but does not aid in alignment due to the zig-zag pattern of the current state of the document.

Comment: Do you wish to just move _USA_, move _USA_ and a following space, or _USA_ plus everything remaining on the line up to the end of that line? Please click [edit] and tell us.

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you give some sample lines of text and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there are only spaces at position 130 and just before, you can do in 2-step.

1. Add 130 spaces before `USA`:

   - find what: `\bUSA\b`
   - Replace with: `_________________$0`  # (I use _ instead o space for better visual) add as many spaces as needed to move USA on each line ahead more than 130 characters from beginning of line.
   - **CHECK** *Regular expression*
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>
2. Remove superfluous spaces before `USA`

   - Find what: `^.{129}\K\h+(?=\bUSA\b)`
   - Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
   - **CHECK** *Regular expression*
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: @klepp0906: If you add, let's say, 130 spaces, then, `USA` will be moved **after** position 130, then you'll got your result when you remove spaces between position 130 and the new position of `USA`. QED.

Comment: that did it, thank you very much!